# MongoDB Max Query with PHP not finish execution

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have this query:

```
$data = $collection->aggregate(
    array('$match' => array(
        'PATIENT_ID' => array(
            '$in' => $arrayPatientId
        )
    )),
    array('$group' => array(
        '_id' => '$PATIENT_ID',
        'massi1' => array(
            '$max' => $dnameth_value
        )
    ))
);
```

where I search the `MAX` value of `dnameth_value` in my collection for a specific `ID` present in array (`$arrayPatientId`)

The query runs for more than a minute and does not stop and I don't know why? Any help please?

Comment: try to use something like `explain` in mysql